# Best way to send data from a consumer to a producer in Node.js on Kafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I'm an absolute beginner in both Kafka and Node.js, so I'm asking the experts...

I'm just trying to build a prototype of a pipeline for data transformation. As you must have guessed, the pipeline is powered by Kafka: each stage in the data transformation process is represented by a topic.

The data transformation is in charge to Node.js: each transformer has both a consumer reading from a topic and a producer writing to the next topic in the pipeline.

Now I'm in the situation where I cannot figure out how to connect the consumer to the producer in Node.js.

I'm using the `kafka-node` module from `npm` whose API provides these handy methods, but I have no idea what should I use in the implementation of the `push()` and `pop()` methods:

```
consumer.on('message', (message) => {
  process(message, callback);  // do stuff
});

var callback(err, result) => {
   push(result) // Where should I push the results into?
}

producer.on('ready', function () {
  var payloads = pop(); // Where should I pop data from?
  producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

producer.on('error', function (err) {})
```

I suppose I should write in some sort of a queue provided by Node.js or alike.

What is the best option for this use case? Please notice I'm on Node v6.2.0